# Moving user accounts from server to local

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, domain-controller

My company has a Windows server that we mainly use for file sharing. When the company was larger its main purpose was to be a domain server for logins. We sold a large portion of the company, and I feel it doesn't make sense to maintain this aging beast so I'm trying to replace it with a NAS. Problem is, I'm not sure how to move the individual accounts on personal computers from using the server to log in to logging in locally (and have all the files and applications maintained).

If anyone has any links to tutorials or documentation on how to do this, I'd be very grateful. I am not a sys admin by training, and personally I much prefer Linux to Windows server. We are using Windows Server for Small Business 2008.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Create a local account for each user on each PC.
2. Unjoin each PC from the domain.
3. Copy the contents of the profile on each local computer from the domain user's profile to the new local user's profile.
4. Decommission your server.

---

I would advise you to approach this with care and caution. There are a lot of benefits that come from an Active Directory domain that you don't get with a workgroup, such as Group Policy, centralized authentication and authorization, etc. It really is a step in the wrong direction in most cases.

Comment: I'd agree with that group policy comment, but we are a very tiny office now with roughly five people all of whom are very computer savvy. I also just want a "quick" fix in case this server dies unexpectedly. Thank you for the answer!